# How to apply function to consecutive pairs of values from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary

```
tickers = {'BTC': [200, 149, 98, 44], 'ETH': [200, 320, 405, 460]}
```

`now` and `prev` are elements of lists.

We compare this element and previous element in list.

For example in BTC:

> 149 with 200
>     98 with 149
>     44 with 98

```
# check state . describe state
def check_state(now, prev):
    state = None
    if now >= prev:
        if now <= 1.5 * prev:
                state = 0
    if now >= 1.5 * prev:
        state = 1
    if now < prev:
        if now * 1.5 >= prev:
               state = 2
    if now * 1.5 < prev:
        state = 3
    return state
```

I want to get new dictionary with tickers and states in every day.
First day no state because first day didn't have previous.

```
tickers_state = {'BTC': [None, 3, 3, 3], 'ETH': [None, 1, 0, 0]}
```

where elements are state in every day of each ticker.

How can i do it?

Comment: ok. 
1) At first, I iterate all elements in ticker dict
2) After i iterate all elements in every list
3) After i try check every item
----------------------------------------
How to igrore first item? What is argument of function?

Comment: @Freedomillusions Your question is not clear. For example you compare 149 with 200, with 4 different `if:else` conditions in your function and just expect one value as your comparison? Your question should be as clear as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reverse the order of input arguments of `check_state` from `def check_state(now, prev):` to `def check_state(prev, now):` then the problem of applying a function to consecutive pairs of values of your lists becomes quite easy. I came up with the following function:

```
import itertools


def apply_pairwise(values,
                   function):
    """
    Applies function to consecutive pairs of elements from an input list
    """
    def pairwise(iterable):
        """
        s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s3), ...
        """
        a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return zip(a, b)

    yield from itertools.chain([None],
                               itertools.starmap(function, pairwise(values)))
```

**Examples of usage:**

```
>>> btc = [200, 149, 98, 44]
>>> list(apply_pairwise(btc, check_state))
[None, 2, 3, 3]
>>> eth = [200, 320, 405, 460]
>>> list(apply_pairwise(eth, check_state))
[None, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

**If you can't reverse the inputs:**

If it's impossible to change the order of inputs, we could adopt our function a bit:

```
import itertools


def apply_pairwise(values,
                   function,
                   *,
                   reverse=False):
    """
    Applies function to consecutive pairs of elements from an input list
    """
    def pairwise(iterable):
        """
        s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s3), ...
        or -> (s1,s0), (s2,s1), (s3,s2), ... if reverse
        """
        a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)

        if reverse:
            return zip(b, a)
        return zip(a, b)

    yield from itertools.chain([None],
                               itertools.starmap(function, pairwise(values)))
```

and you could use it like this:

```
>>> btc = [200, 149, 98, 44]
>>> list(apply_pairwise(btc, check_state, reverse=True))
[None, 2, 3, 3]
>>> eth = [200, 320, 405, 460]
>>> list(apply_pairwise(eth, check_state, reverse=True))
[None, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

**Explanation:**

In order to get consecutive pairs of elements, we could use a helper function from recipes of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

It works like this:

```
>>> list(pairwise(range(5)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Now for each pair of elements we would like to apply your `check_state` function. Here [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) can be useful. It works like this:

```
>>> list(itertools.starmap(pow, [(2, 3), (2, 10), (10, 3), (3, 4)]))
[8, 1024, 1000, 81]
```

The only thing left is to prepend the values yielded by `starmap` by `None`. As `starmap` makes an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), we could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to combine the first `None` with the rest of the elements.

---

P.S.: Applying this to values of your `tickers` dict should be easy enough. I will leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare each consecutive pair of values in your lists with a function that loops through the list and uses enumerate to enable access to the previous list item for comparison. Then use dict comprehension with your function to produce a mapped version of your original dict with the compared values.

In the example below, it loops through a slice of the list starting with the second list item so the previous element is accessed by the current value of `i` because the slice has essentially shifted the index values by 1.

```
tickers = {'BTC': [200, 149, 98, 44], 'ETH': [200, 320, 405, 460]}

def check_states(data):
    states = [None]
    for i, n in enumerate(data[1:]):
        state = None
        p = data[i]
        (low, high) = (p / 1.5, p * 1.5)
        if n >= p:
            state = 0 if n <= high else 1
        else:
            state = 2 if n >= low else 3           
        states.append(state)    
    return states

tickers_state = {k: check_states(v) for k, v in tickers.items()}

print(tickers_state)
# OUTPUT
# {'BTC': [None, 2, 3, 3], 'ETH': [None, 1, 0, 0]}
```